# gitignore not ignoring files properly

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore some files in git but git is staging the files mentioned in `gitignore`.

My `gitignore`.

```
*.exe
*.out
*.app
```

**Local Repository Strucutre**

```
algorithms/          //contains cpp files with .exe
data structure/      //contains cpp files with .exe
git.gitignore        <-- gitignore
README.md
LICENSE
```

**Staging files**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make any sense I'm afraid: `git add .` will ignore files mentioned in a well-formed `.gitignore` file. Pushing a commit to a remote repository does not and cannot respect `.gitignore` (because 1. it would change the content of the commit which would change the SHA, and 2. you can stage and commit ignored files by adding them explicitly). I suspect that your `.gitignore` file is not well formed, or you have misunderstood what's happening.

Comment: "When I run the command git add . it stages all the files including the files mentioned in the .gitignore " - no, that should not happen. I just tested it - "git add ." will *not* stage files covered by .gitignore, it will silently ignore them. Even if you *explicitly* add an ignored file ("git add my-ignored-file"), git will still warn ("The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files").

Comment: So there is probably something else going wrong. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you are adding files, where an ignored file is added by "git add"?

Comment: Voting to close (for now), because details are missing.

Comment: About the example: Ideally, edit your Q with a list of git commands that create a new repo, add .gitignore etc., where in the end a "git add" adds an ignored file.

Comment: @sleske I mentioned more details to the question

Comment: Did you check if the same happens with other files that are mentioned in your `.gitignore` file ? Or perhaps you ran `git add` before you included the file in the `.gitignore` ? Finally, is your `.gitignore` placed in the root of your repo?

Comment: @minasrc until now only `.exe` files are generated that need to be ignored

Comment: You write "my 'gitignore' file". The filename must be ".gitignore", not "gitignore" (note the leading dot)

Comment: @knittl My file name is git.gitignore

Comment: @SidharthMudgil the file must be called ".gitignore". Nothing else. ".gitignore" is the only filename that works.

Comment: Yes, but could you test all the elements of the ckecklist I provided and share the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see in the background of the first image, you have named your file `git.gitignore`, The name must be `.gitignore`

Comment: is this invalid name?

Comment: If I rename my .gitignore to git.gitignore all my files including in my working directory will be staged on a git add .
Including the .exe file.

Comment: The only valid name is `.gitignore`. Any other name will be discarded.